# JPMML A predicate evaluates to unknown (i.e. a null reference) if the input value is missing

Tags: java, null, pmml

I am using jpmml.evaluator.version 1.3.4 & jpmml.model.version 1.3.5.

I prepare the arguments for the evaluate and get an error :
org.jpmml.evaluator.MissingValueException (at or around line 10678): decisionFunction_1
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.mining.MiningModelEvaluator.evaluateSegmentation(MiningModelEvaluator.java:436)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.mining.MiningModelEvaluator.evaluateClassification(MiningModelEvaluator.java:240)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.mining.MiningModelEvaluator.evaluate(MiningModelEvaluator.java:207)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.mining.MiningModelEvaluator.evaluate(MiningModelEvaluator.java:185)

The code :

```
//Feature class has 2 fields: String name, Object value

 public Double evaluate(List<Feature> givenFeaturesValue)  {
  Map<FieldName, FieldValue> arguments = new HashMap<>();

List<InputField> inputFields = evaluator.getInputFields();
Map<FieldName, InputField> featureProperties= new HashMap<>(inputFields.size());
        for(InputField inputField : inputFields) {
                    featureProperties.put(inputField.getName(), inputField);
        }

for(Entry<FieldName, InputField> featureProperty: featureProperties.entrySet()) {
            FieldValue value = featureProperty.getValue().prepare(null);    
            arguments.put(featureProperty.getKey(), value);
    }

    for(Entry<FieldName, InputField> featureProperty: featureProperties.entrySet()) {
        for(Feature givenFeature: givenFeaturesValue) {
            if(givenFeature.getFieldName().equals(featureProperty.getKey().getValue())) {
                FieldValue value = givenFeature.getValue().prepare(featureProperty.getValue());             
                arguments.put(featureProperty.getKey(), value);
            }
        }
    }

Map<FieldName, ?> results = evaluator.evaluate(arguments);

   //after this line I get the error
}
```

PMML file :

```
<DataDictionary>
    <DataField name="GENDER" optype="categorical" dataType="string">
        <Value value="0"/>
        <Value value="1"/>
    </DataField>
    <DataField name="1GA" optype="categorical" dataType="string">
        <Value value="1GA DEFAULT"/>
        <Value value=""/>
        <Value value="&quot;"/>
        <Value value="#"/>
        <Value value="#NUM#"/>
</DataField>
    <DataField name="DB10" optype="categorical" dataType="integer">
        <Value value="0"/>
        <Value value="1"/>
    </DataField>
 <DataField name="ILR" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
 </DataDictionary>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just supply a non-`null` value (instead of a `null` value) for this input field.

This exception is JPMML-Evaluator's equivalent of `java.lang.NullPointerException`. You do know how to deal with NPEs in Java (and other JVM based languages)?

Comment: I am not sure what is the correct way to initialize the arguments map. I added example of the PMML file. If there is no value for the argument should it be empty / null/ 0.0 ?

Comment: `Evaluator#getInputFields()` gives you a list of input fields. Your arguments map must supply a value for all of them. Some input fields do accept `null` values, some don't - you can distinguish between those two modes using JPMML-Evaluator APIs. In your code example, you're passing a `null` default value to all input fields without doing any pre-checks. Apparently, your model doesn't support missing values, so it's the right behaviour to fail fast with a MissingValueException when it's executed with an incomplete arguments map.